# LINQ to SQL, sorting by a related table

Tags: linq

I'm trying to order the values in a related table using [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL).

I have 2 tables. Menu and MenuSection. They are related one to many on Menu.MenuId == MenuSection.MenuId

Currently, I'm pulling this information using the following query

```
var menus = from m in _context.Menus                        
                    select m;
```

This gets fed into an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) page and works fine.

I'd like to be able to sort the data the column MenuSection.Order

I've tried doing this:

```
var menus = from m in _context.Menus 
                join ms in _context.MenuSections on m.MenuId equals ms.MenuId
                orderby ms.Order ascending select m;
```

But it's bringing back a set of data that is incorrect. It displays repeated Menu information.

EDIT: To clarify what i'm expecting the data shoud be:

There are x Menu's in Menu.

Each Menu has many MenuSection's

I'd like to list out each Menu and their related MenuSection.
The MenuSections need to be in order based on MenuSection.Order

```
Menu 1
- MenuSection 1, Order = 1
- MenuSection 3, Order = 2
Menu 2
- MenuSection 4, Order = 1
- MenuSection 2, Order = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Round 3:** That last revision to the question clarifies it a lot.  It sounds like what you really need is a group-by. Those are harder to get right without the IntelliSense but I'll try my best:

```
var groupings =
    from m in _context.Menus
    orderby m.Foo
    from ms in m.MenuSections
    orderby ms.Order
    group ms by m;

foreach (var group in groupings)
{
    Menu menu = group.Key;
    // use the Menu

    foreach (MenuSection ms in group)
    {
        // use the MenuSection
    }
}
```

Now I added an extra `orderby m.Foo` where `Foo` is some property that I think you might want on `Menu`. Otherwise you aren't guaranteed to know the order of the top level menus.

Also note what I was saying earlier that the `m.MenuSections` is really a helper that is similar to `from ms in _context.MenuSections where ms.MenuId == m.MenuId`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, either don't work.
for the first one, "let order = m.MenuSection.Order" isn't valid. 
m.MenuSections is available but you can't directly reference the Order column. 

The same goes for the second query. ms.Order can't be referenced.

Comment: Ahh OK, that means that my original understanding of the question was backwards. You have **one** Menu to **many** MenuSections. I'll add a different query for that scenario. Now I'm a little confused at how you are wanting to display this. Are you expecting the menu to be repeated for each MenuSection it is in?

Comment: just updated the main question. Your second answer does not work as it displays repeated Menu's.  Thanks for your help on this so far too

Comment: That makes more sense. So MenuSection is like a MenuItem? I'll update my answer as I think you are probably going to want a GroupBy. How do you want to sort the Menus themselves?

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay in replying. 

Your solution worked and I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks for your help on this one. :)

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like this? ...

```
var menus = (from m in _context.Menus
            join ms in _context.MenuSections on m.MenuId equals ms.MenuId
            orderby ms.Order ascending select m).Distinct();
```

or maybe this...

```
var menus = (from m in _context.Menus
            join ms in _context.MenuSections on m.MenuId equals ms.MenuId
            select new {m, ms.Order})
            .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
            .Select(x => x.m)
            .Distinct();
```

In that second case, you're projecting the sort column into a new type, sorting on it, then selecting just the original object, and distincting on that.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI, I did manage to make this work by sorting as I performed the output.

My original intention was to have a presorted data set to work with.

Here is an example of what I meant:

```
var menus = from m in _context.Menus select m;

foreach (var menu in menus)
{
     Console.WriteLine(menu.Name);
     foreach (var menuSection in menu.MenuSections.OrderBy(o => o.Order))
     {
          Console.WriteLine("\t" + menuSection.Name + ", " + menuSection.Order);
     }
 }
```